# RabbitMQ: Few messages remain unacknowledged

Tags: java, rabbitmq

I have a consumer that reads from RabbitMQ and writes to my database. The Consumer class that I use, is user defined, and it implements Callable.

Manual Consumer Method:

```
public static void consume(Queue queue, String consumerName, int threadCount, int prefetchCount) throws Exception {
    DbUtil.initializeConnectionPool();

    Connection connection = RabbitMqUtils.getConnection();
    Channel channel = connection.createChannel();
    QueueingConsumer consumer = new QueueingConsumer(channel);

    channel.basicQos(threadCount * prefetchCount);
    queue.initiateConsumer(channel, consumer);

    System.out.println("MQ Server: " + connection.getAddress() + ":" + connection.getPort());
    System.out.println("Queue: " + queue.name);

    // Multi-threading code.
    threadPool = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(threadCount);
    Class c = Class.forName(consumerName);

    while (true) {
        Consumer consumerInstance = (Consumer) c.newInstance();
        java.sql.Connection dbConnection = null;
        QueueingConsumer.Delivery delivery = null;

        try {
            delivery = consumer.nextDelivery();
            dbConnection = DbUtil.getConnectionFromPool();
            consumerInstance.setConsumerDetails(new String(delivery.getBody()), dbConnection, channel, queue, delivery);
            threadPool.submit(consumerInstance);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            if (delivery != null) {
                Consumer.reQueueMessage(delivery, new String(delivery.getBody()), channel, queue, e);
            }
            if (dbConnection != null) {
                dbConnection.close();
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Call Method:

```
@Override
public Object call() throws Exception {
    try {
        doWork(this.message, this.dbConnection);
        channel.basicAck(this.delivery.getEnvelope().getDeliveryTag(), false);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Consumer.dumpMsg(e.getMessage(), "Error Msg");
        Consumer.reQueueMessage(this.delivery, new String(this.delivery.getBody()), this.channel, this.queue, e);
    } finally {
        java.sql.Connection dbConnection = this.dbConnection;
        if (dbConnection != null) {
            dbConnection.close();
        }
    }

    return null;
}
```

The `doWork` is my method which is overridden in the children of the `Consumer` class. The issue is that 1 in about a 1000 messages get stuck in the queue in the `unacked` state. I can only get them out of the `unacked` state by stopping and then starting the consumer. My guess is that the acknowledgement gets lost in the network traffic. I want to know if there is a way to cause the messages to only remain in the `unacked` state for sometime, before going back to the queue, to be re-consumed.

Comment: Are you sharing channels between threads? That could be one reason for the problem. About your other question, no, there's no timeout for messages that are pending ack

Comment: @old_sound, yes, it does look like I am sharing a channel.